# In data warehouse, can fact table contain two same records?

Tags: data-warehouse

If a user ordered same product with two different order_id;
The orders are created within a same date-hour granularity, for example

```
order#1 2019-05-05 17:23:21
order#2 2019-05-05 17:33:21
```

In the data warehouse, should we put them into two rows like this (**Option 1**):

```
| id  | user_key | product_key | date_key | time_key | price | quantity |
|-----|----------|-------------|----------|----------|-------|----------|
| 001 | 1111     | 22          | 123      | 456      | 10    | 1        |
| 002 | 1111     | 22          | 123      | 456      | 10    | 2        |
```

Or just put them in one row with the aggregated quantity (**Option 2**):

```
| id  | user_key | product_key | date_key | time_key | price | quantity |
|-----|----------|-------------|----------|----------|-------|----------|
| 001 | 1111     | 22          | 123      | 456      | 10    | 3        |
```

I know if I put the `order_id` as a degenerate dimension in the fact table, it should be **Option 1**. But in our case, we don't really want to keep the order_id.

Also I once read an article that says that when all dimensions are filtered out, there should be only one row of data in the fact table. If this statement is correct, the **Option 2** will be the choice.

Is there a principle where I can refer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, fact tables in a data warehouse should be designed at the most detailed grain available. You can always aggregate data from the lower granularity to the higher one, while the opposite is not true - if you combine the records, some information is lost permanently. If you ever need it later (even though you might not see it now), you'll regret the decision.

I would recommend the following approach: in a data warehouse, keep order number as degenerate dimension. Then, when you publish a star schema, you might build a pre-aggregated version of the table (skip order number, group identical records by date/hour). This way, you can have smaller/cleaner fact table in your dimensional model, and yet preserve more detailed data in the DW.

Comment: thanks, what do you mean by `publish a star schema` and the `pre-aggregate version of the table`? The data warehouse which I am designing will be the only data source of our BI and report system.

Comment: End tools (reporting systems) shouldn't have direct access to the data warehouse tables. Instead, a subset of the content is materialized (copied) to a dedicated server, database, or at least a schema, which BI tools can then access. During this process, you can create multiple versions of the same data (for example, with the identical records grouped by hour). Some people provide data access via views/SQL queries, but saving a static, disposable copy is a much more reliable and convenient design.

Comment: what you are talking about is the **data mart**? Sorry I'm very new to the data warehouse field. I have to ask some basic/.

Comment: A datamart, in plain english, is one fact table and its dimensions. A data warehouse is the set of all data marts.

Comment: @nsousa do you mean a data mart always contains *ONLY* one fact table? What confuse me is RADO's comment, *<a subset of the content is materialized (copied) to a dedicated server, database, or at least a schema, which BI tools can then access.>*. What is this process called?

Comment: @RADO *<fact tables in a data warehouse should be designed at the most detailed grain available>* do you mean we should keep all the information from the source data into data warehouse? If all my data is extracted from *one* source database, the only difference will be *ER model* v.s. *multi-dim model*?

Comment: Yes, you should keep all information from the source(s). No, there are usually more differences than just structure, even for one source. Usually, extracted data is enhanced in data warehouse: missing values are plugged, bad records are fixed or flagged, calculated attributes are added, additional structures are built: hierarchies, bridge tables, calendar tables, junk dimensions, etc. You can also bring in supplementary data not available at the source: exchange rates, settings, charts of account and other classification schemes, and so on.

Comment: I'd recommend to read a couple of books on data warehousing, from Kimball and Ingham. If you are building a data set to support a small, specific application, that might be not very important. But if your goal is to build a company-wide data warehouse, you must understand its architecture.

Comment: **data mart** is a subset of the main data warehouse dedicated to support a specific subject/area. It can contain multiple fact tables, but it's simplified and optimized for a specific task. For example, you data warehouse might contain 50 dimensions and 40 fact tables, covering the entire business. Then, you publish a subset of them, say, 6 dimensions and 2 fact tables, for Accounting department. That subset is "Accounting department's data mart".

Comment: @RADO  Thanks, I've just read *The Data Warehouse Toolkit*, many of my doubts are clear.  Another question is, is this modeling method no longer popular? Because through the search, I feel that there has been less and less discussion about dimensional modeling in the last year or two.

Comment: I would avoid drawing profound conclusions from a limited research. If you want to develop sound judgement, attend conferences or other relevant events where BI experts discuss trends and latest developments. In general, I think the opposite is true - interactive BI tools such as Power BI, Tableau, Qlick, etc are rapidly growing, and they all need proper dimensional models.